# Logging request and response xml in Axis2

Tags: logging, apache-axis

I have written an axis2 client. I want to log the request and response xml generated at client side(Log file at client side). There is facility to do logging by creating handlers at server side. Is there any same kind of facility for client side as well?

Could anyone please help me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

-Ritesh

Answer (score 1):

Yes, axis2 handlers can be associated both at the service and as well as client end.

Thanks...